# How to escape whitespace when running Rscript from command line?

Tags: r, bash, command-line

I am currently trying to call Rscript on a file that has white spaces:

```
Rscript "File Name with White Spaces.R"
```

and it keeps giving an error that the file could not be found. I have tried to add in escapes, such as

```
Rscript "File\ Name\ with\ White\ Spaces.R"
```

all the way up to three escapes, but to no avail. Is there a simple trick to doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand, you mean use single quotes?

Comment: double quotes wil correctly escape spaces within filenames in shell.  Are you in the correct directory for that relative path to be accurate?

Comment: Are you executing the program `Rscript` from BASH as shell? In that case, the filename including the spaces is correctly passed to the argument vector (a.k.a. `argv`) of the executed program in the first case. So, that part is correct. If that doesn't work, the n`Rscript` does something bad with it. BTW: Second form works, too, even if you removed the double quotes. BTW 2: Tab completion will not just save you typing but automatically make sure that the files are written correctly, use that!

Comment: I checked and I am in the right directory but the above still fails to work. do you have any ideas? I am in centos

Comment: Maybe rename file to something more simple (eg., `file.R`)?

Comment: what does it do when you use tab to autocomplete the filename?

Comment: ...also, please [edit] your question to add the full error message verbatim.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the whitespaces. I am trying to set the working directory with `setwd('my/wd')` and it's not working with directories containing spaces in their name. I tried also to escape the whitespaces with the backslash, but nothing changes.